# how to change pulled docker image zeppelin port?

Tags: docker, apache-zeppelin

docker pull dylanmei/zeppelin:latest 
I pulled the docker image 
some how it default with port 8080 
if I want to change the config where should I change it?

Comment: `-p myport:8080`

Comment: 0a5b7f42dbbf        dylanmei/zeppelin:latest               "bin/zeppelin.sh"        18 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes              0.0.0.0:8088-8089->8088-8089/tcp                           zeppelin
but i can not access to the server localhost:8088 or 8089